# Error when calling function from imported file in React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Quick question but its been bugging me for a while. I am trying to call the `signUpUser()` function in the code below but it is not getting called. I cannot write `this.props.signUpUser()` so O do not know how else to call the function except for writing how I've done below.

- FYI I've removed the return code to keep the code block small

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { signUpUser } from '../redux/actions/userActions.js';

function Register() {
  const [newUserData, setnewUserData] = useState('');
  const [showRegistered, setShowRegistered] = useState(false);
  if(showRegistered) {
    signUpUser(newUserData);
    return(

    )
  } else {

  }

}
```

Comment: Are you using `mapDispatchToProps`?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: It looks like you are using redux in this project. I suggest that you read the redux documentation to understand how to use it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

try doing this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {

return {
signup: () => dispatch(signUp()),
   }
}
```

connect it to your component:

```
export default connect({}, mapDispatchToProps)(Register);
```

Now, if you wan't to dispatch your action, you can use `signup()`. To use actions, you must do them inside a redux dispatch function. Let me know if it worked for you :)